# checking for a value in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

My function to check if a value is in an array returns false every time, even if it should be true.

When I change var value to be, let's say 20, and I run the page until 20 appears in the array, it works and returns true. However when the value is the prompt, and I type in a number that appears in the array, I always get false.

```
function checkIfInArray(n, anArray) {
    return anArray.indexOf(n) > -1;
}
var array = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101);
}
alert("The array is " + array);
var value = prompt("Enter a value to check if it is in the array");
var result = checkIfInArray(value, array);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array contains numbers, `prompt()` returns a string. You need to convert the string into a number, which you can do with [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```js
function checkIfInArray(n,anArray) {
  return anArray.indexOf(n) > -1;
}
var array=new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
      {
        array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
    }
alert("The array is " + array);
var value=parseInt(prompt("Enter a value to check if it is in the array"), 10);
var result=checkIfInArray(value,array);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```js
function checkIfInArray(n,anArray) {
  return anArray.indexOf(parseInt(n)) > -1; // parse int . here was the problem
}
var array=new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
      {
        array[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*101);
    }
alert("The array is " + array);
var value=prompt("Enter a value to check if it is in the array");
var result=checkIfInArray(value,array);
alert(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a type issue, the prompt result is a **string** not an **int** and the `indexOf` method use a strict mode to compare the elements, so you should **cast** the value to an int before call `indexOf`:

```
return anArray.indexOf(parseInt(n)) > -1;
```

*Note that the `Array.indexOf` is not supported in IE8

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting that error because the prompt is sending a string and not a number. Try using `parseInt()` to convert the string to an integer to test the value.

You could do either

```
var value = parseInt(prompt("Enter a value to check if it is in the array"));
```

or

```
var result = checkIfInArray(parseInt(value), array);
```